# Is it bad to throw an exception and ignore "reaches end of non-void function" warnings?

Tags: c++

My code:

```
QSerialPortInfo getCentralInfo()
{
    const QList<QSerialPortInfo> infoList =
            QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    for (auto it = infoList.cbegin();
         it != infoList.cend(); ++it) {
        if (it->manufacturer() == "1a86") {
            happyTalk("Znaleziono centralkę.");
            return *it;
        }
    }
    escape("Nie znaleziono centralki.");
}

void escape(QString errorMsg) {
    qDebug() << "[!] " << errorMsg;
    throw;
}

void happyTalk(QString msg) {
    qDebug() << "[\u2713] " << msg;
}
```

Is it elegant to stop the application like that and why is it not? I'm getting debugger warnings but I think the debugger is wrong here. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `[[noreturn]]` attribute to `escape`, and actually throw an object.

`[[noreturn]]` tells the compiler, optimizer and hopefully warning generator that `escape` never returns, so it should (in an ideal world) block that error.

Comment: `[[noreturn]]` is C++11 -- upgrade your compiler! @smsware

Comment: I'm using C++11, do you know for sure that qmake developers implemented this?

Comment: @smsware I do not know what your compiler's actual C++11 support is.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that

```
throw;
```

does not mean "throw some exception." It means "rethrow the exception currently being processed." If you execute `throw` with no active exception, I believe it calls `std::terminate` to end the program.

A more elegant way to handle this would either be to throw an exception (perhaps a `std::logic_error`) to indicate that something bad happened and transfer control to an error handler, or to exit the program by calling `exit` or `abort`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This didn't do the trick (it stopped to warn only when the escape was called, it warned when everything was fine - I'm puzzled) but I've exchanged the "throw" with "exit(0)" anyway. :-)